# Getting Null pointer exception while capturing and saving an image using android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to capture and save an image through an Android emulator, image is being captured, but the file being saved is corrupted.

What could be causing this? can anyone help me identify possible error points?

Below is my code:

```
**public void onCreate**(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    **Intent** intent = new **Intent**("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    try {
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
    } 

    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    intent.putExtra(**MediaStore**.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
**protected void onActivityResult**(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            StoreImage(this, data.getData(),
            mediaFile);
            finish();
        } 

        else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // User cancelled the image capture
        } 

        else {
            finish();
            try {
            } 

            catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**The Stack trace is below::**

```
04-05 23:55:40.369: E/AndroidRuntime(534): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-05 23:55:40.369: E/AndroidRuntime(534): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{camera.android/camera.android.CameraActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: file
04-05 23:55:40.369: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)

04-05 23:55:40.369: E/AndroidRuntime(534): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: file
04-05 23:55:40.369: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:441)
04-05 23:55:40.369: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at camera.android.CameraActivity.getOutputMediaFileUri(CameraActivity.java:72)
04-05 23:55:40.369: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at camera.android.CameraActivity.onCreate(CameraActivity.java:34)
04-05 23:55:40.369: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-05 23:55:40.369: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-05 23:55:40.369: E/AndroidRuntime(534):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
```

Comment: would be better if can post your crash log.

Comment: see my answer here if below solution is not for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334378/null-pointer-exception-on-file-uri/43228221#43228221

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check whether you added the below permission in manifest file::

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

also in the

```
fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
```

I think you must attach the file name that you want to save too, and giving only the path is not enough....

Comment: In the function getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE), I have defined the path where the file is being saved,  File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg")

Comment: check whether fileUri is null or not. and also what is StoreImage(this, data.getData(), mediaFile);

Comment: My file is being created, but it dosen't contain the image. It is corrupted

Answer (score 4):

Interchange this line,

```
if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
```

to

```
 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
```

First check whether the child activity is done its work successfully or not.

Answer (score 1):

"@ Agarwal : on calling the onActivityResult"

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                StoreImage(this, data.getData(), mediaFile);
                finish();

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // User cancelled the image capture
            } else {
                finish();
                try {

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

"If the result is success, then the data from intern is stored n file which is created and saved as jpeg format"

```
public static void StoreImage(Context mContext, Uri imageLoc, File imageDir) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try {
            bm = Media.getBitmap(mContext.getContentResolver(), imageLoc);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(imageDir);
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            bm.recycle();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code,

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    File file=getOutputMediaFile(1);
    picUri = Uri.fromFile(file); // create
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,picUri); // set the image file

    startActivityForResult(i, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
```

where getOutputMediaFile(int) will be,

```
/** Create a File for saving an image */
private  File getOutputMediaFile(int type){
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
              Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyApplication");

    /**Create the storage directory if it does not exist*/
    if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){
        if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**Create a media file name*/
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if (type == 1){
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
        "IMG_"+ timeStamp + ".png");
    } else {
        return null;
    }

    return mediaFile;
}
```

and finally,

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Intent i;
        switch (requestCode) {
        case CAPTURE_IMAGE:
            //THIS IS YOUR Uri
            Uri uri=picUri; 
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

cheers....:)