# Unfortunately, appname has stopped when starting a new Activity

Tags: android

When I click on a button to start an **Activity**, it gives the following error:

Unfortunately appName has stopped.

I have the following CameraActivity.java file:

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity{

    // LogCat tag
    private static final String TAG = CameraActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    // Camera activity request codes
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;

    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    private Uri fileUri; // file url to store image/video

    private Button btnCapturePicture, btnRecordVideo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera_main);

        btnCapturePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
        btnRecordVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecordVideo);

        /**
         * Capture image button click event
         */
        btnCapturePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // capture picture
                captureImage();
            }
        });

        /**
         * Record video button click event
         */
        btnRecordVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // record video
                recordVideo();
            }
        });


        // Checking camera availability
        if (!isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Your device doesn't support camera",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // will close the app if the device does't have camera
            finish();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checking device has camera hardware or not
     * */
    private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera() {
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // this device has a camera
            return true;
        } else {
            // no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void goBack(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, IncidentMenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    /**
     * Launching camera app to capture image
     */
    private void captureImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * Launching camera app to record video
     */
    private void recordVideo() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

        // set video quality
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
        // name

        // start the video capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * Here we store the file url as it will be null after returning from camera
     * app
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // save file url in bundle as it will be null on screen orientation
        // changes
        outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // get the file url
        fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
    }



    /**
     * Receiving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // if the result is capturing Image
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                // successfully captured the image
                // launching upload activity
                launchUploadActivity(true);


            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                // video successfully recorded
                // launching upload activity
                launchUploadActivity(false);

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                // user cancelled recording
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

            } else {
                // failed to record video
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    private void launchUploadActivity(boolean isImage){
        Intent i = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, UploadActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("filePath", fileUri.getPath());
        i.putExtra("isImage", isImage);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    /**
     * ------------ Helper Methods ----------------------
     * */

    /**
     * Creating file uri to store image/video
     */
    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /**
     * returning image / video
     */
    private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        // External sdcard location
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + Config.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }

}
```

In my logCat I have these errors appearing:

```
01-01 22:12:30.280 19343-19343/com.example.infonet.emonitor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException: file
        at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:444)
        at com.example.infonet.emonitor.CameraActivity.getOutputMediaFileUri(CameraActivity.java:230)
        at com.example.infonet.emonitor.CameraActivity.captureImage(CameraActivity.java:115)
        at com.example.infonet.emonitor.CameraActivity.access$000(CameraActivity.java:20)
        at com.example.infonet.emonitor.CameraActivity$1.onClick(CameraActivity.java:64)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-01 22:12:31.490 648-734/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
```

I can't pin point what could be wrong as I am yet to be grounded in android and interpreting these errors is of no understanding to me.

Comment: Did you try to debug the app? Maybe the Uri is being null and that is the reason of your problem

Comment: @JohnJoe: you are right, Tonye Boro : your code throwing exception at this line  fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

Comment: @AniruddhParihar, could you please help me out cause I have tried all I could but still no success.

Comment: follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31334378/null-pointer-exception-on-file-uri